# Combing two SQL tables to create a singular table in HTML

Tags: html, mysql, sql, web-development-server

thanks for trying to help!
I've got a bit of a complex issue, and I'm trying to figure out how to solve it.
Essentially i'm trying to generate an HTML table that derives all of its values from my SQL database about authors. In this table, Im trying to display the ID, their first name, last name, and total number of books each author has written.

There are two tables I'm interacting with in sql, and can't quite figure out how to combine them to get just one table (in HTML).

The first table consist of an ID, First Name, and Last name.
The second table consist of AuthorID(Foreign Key referencing ID), and a BookID.

Essentially the total number of occurrences of each AuthorID is how many books they have written. So I'm needing to find a way to incorporate this into my preexisting select statement.

I have successfully made a table with the ID, their first name, last name, but can seem to figure out how to reference the second table and count the instances. I've included my HTML, and some database Screenshots.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
        <h2> <a class="head" href="base.php" style="text-decoration: none;">Database Project</a> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm main" href="#" role="button">Sign Out</a></h2>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h3>Author Report:</h3><br>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Zion");
                if ($conn-> connect_error){
                    die("Connection Failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
                }
                $sql = "SELECT ID,FirstName,LastName from Author";
                $result = $conn-> query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows>0){
                    while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
                        echo "<tr><td>". $row["ID"] . "</td><td>". $row["FirstName"]."</td><td>". $row["LastName"]. "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    echo"</table>";
                }
                $conn-> close()
                ?>


    </div>

</body>
```

SQL Images:
[image]

[image]
Thanks!

Currently What I have:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To find total no books from Author you can Simply change your query as

```
SELECT ID,FirstName,LastName,(SELECT count(bookId) from books where authorId = Author.id ) as noofbooks from Author
```

Here Sub query find no of books count for each AuthorId.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3>Author Report:</h3><br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>No of Books</th>
    
            </tr>
            <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Zion");
            if ($conn-> connect_error){
                die("Connection Failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
            }
            $sql = "SELECT ID,FirstName,LastName,(SELECT count(bookId) from books where authorId = Author.id ) as noofbooks from Author";
            $result = $conn-> query($sql);
            if($result->num_rows>0){
                while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
                    echo "<tr><td>". $row["ID"] . "</td><td>". $row["FirstName"]."</td><td>". $row["LastName"]. "</td><td>". $row["noofbooks"]. "</td></tr>";
                }
                echo"</table>";
            }
            $conn-> close()
            ?>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I reference this select statement for use in the while loop, as I reference the ID, FirstName, and last name?

Comment: hey there, I implemented your solution! Much thanks again, however im getting this strange error "Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/authorreport.php on line 38". Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: @NoahSmiley It happens when you have logical errors in your query string i.e.,  `if($result->num_rows>0)` returns a null object. Make sure the query string that you execute is proper.  You should therefore change the if to be something along the lines of: ` if($result && $result->num_rows)`.